# Blender + Ni Mate (Mocap Animation)

Tags: animation, unity

I made an animation with Blender + Ni Mate using the Kinect v2, i have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UPZtS5LVvw

I have my own armature that is copying the ni mate armature, but when i record the animation, blender puts the animation movement on the bones of the ni-mate kinect armature, so when i export the animation in a fbx file and import on unity there's a lot of animation files.

Is it possible to do this animation in to my own armature and export as an fbx or other type of file and import into Unity?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found a solution to it. It's a function called "Bake Action".

Select all the kinect-empties, select the armature you want to have the action on and either use the space bar to search for "bake action" or click the button at the side menu under "Animation". In the pop-up window deselect "Only Selected" and select "Visual Keying", "Clear Constraints" and "Pose". Press "Okay" and your selected armature should now have an Action that is suitable to be played in Unity.

Source for Action baking: https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/topic/271/