# Kinect + Ni Mate Export to Fbx

Tags: animation, .fbx, unreal-engine

I have a setup with the Kinect + Blender + Ni Mate software [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1UPZtS5LVvw).

My recording is all nice and ready. My pose is constrained to the bones of the "Kinect" one. My keyframes are all on empties it appears, but my armature is constrained to those.

I want to now export the animation to FBX. However, when I go to do so, it takes half an hour. When it is finished, the .fbx file is 700kb but if you try to import this into anything (like Unreal Engine 4), it takes another half an hour to load back in and expands RAM memory to a wopping 4+GB with animations everywhere, presumably per bone.

I want 1 animation file for my armature with only what is in the recorded clip. What am I doing wrong?

My settings for export are:

1. Only export Armature
2. only export Selected.
3. Only deformed bones is checked under "Armature" tab
4. Under animation I have checked "Baked anims", "Key all bones", "All actions", Sampling Rate 1.0, Simplify 1.0

I also tried to "bake action" using the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106002/blender-ni-mate-mocap-animation) but that took just as long, broke the animation in blender for me.